# Titanium Appcelerator has no method createTCp

Tags: android, sockets, titanium, sockjs

I'm trying to create a socket connection to SockJS server and following the example given [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/TCP_Socket_API_Spec)
but Titanium keeps on giving me the error "has no method createTCP"

This is the code I'm using

```
var connectingSocket = Ti.Network.createTCP({
host: host,
port: port,
connected:function(e) {
    e.socket.write(Ti.createBuffer({data: "Well, hello there!"}));
},
error:function(e) {
    Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
        title:"Socket error: "+e.errorCode,
        message:e.error
    }).show();
    Ti.API.info("CONNECTION has been closed: "+e.socket.host+":"+e.socket.port);
}
});
connectingSocket.connect();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Ti.Network.Socket.createTCP instead of Ti.Network.createTCP.

Here is the structure of code, as example.

```
var clientSocket = Ti.Network.Socket.createTCP({

    host : hostname,
    port : port,
    connected : function(e) {

        e.socket.write(Ti.createBuffer({
            value : 'A message from a connecting socket.'
        }));
    },
    error : function(e) {
        Ti.API.info('Error (' + e.errorCode + '): ' + e.error);
    }
});
 clientSocket.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added **Socket** to

use `Ti.Network.Socket.createTCP` instead of `Ti.Network.createTCP`